# Why should I accept answers?

Tags: discussion, support

Why should you accept answers on questions? Why does this help when searching for questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should accept answers to questions that provide a **satisfactory answer to your question**.

There are two different filters for searching questions: `no answers` and `no accepted answer`. Not marking a completely satisfactory answer as accepted discourages other users, and may result in a downvote!